# Emberjs not rendering a nested template

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a social app with Ember using the Ember App Kit as a basis. The index page renders fine. On navigating to the nested model, the route fires correctly, and there are no errors in the console, but the view doesn't render. Here is the relevant code:

console

```
Rendering friend with <(subclass of Ember.View):ember2698> Object {fullName: "view:friend"}
Transitioned into 'friends.friend'
```

routes/friends.js

```
var FriendsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return $.getJSON('JSON_ROUTE').then(function(data){
      return data.friends.map(function(friend) {
        return friend;
      });
    });
  }
});

export default FriendsRoute;
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('friends', function() {
    this.resource('friend', { path: '/:friend_id' });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

templates/friends.hbs

```
<div class="friends-list">
    {{#each model}}
        {{#link-to 'friend' this }}
            {{{display_name}}}
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="friend">
    {{ outlet }}
</div>
```

templates/friend.hbs

```
<div>{{ display_name }}</div>
<div>{{ bio }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an application template with an outlet?  (I'm going to assume no, since you didn't mention it)

Additionally at some point you'll need a Friend route, or refreshes won't work.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ElAfAcE/3/edit

```
App.FriendsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [{friend_id:1, color:'red'}, {friend_id:2, color:'yellow'}, {friend_id:3, color:'blue'}];
  }
});

App.FriendRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.modelFor('friends').findProperty('friend_id', parseInt(params.friend_id));
  },
  serialize: function(model){
    return {friend_id: model.friend_id}; 
  }
});
```

Comment: I did have the application template, but not the Friend route. I added the route and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When Ember looks for templates in a nested route, it's looking for it under this id: friends/friend

> Finally, visiting /posts/new will first render the posts template, then render the posts/new template into its outlet.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources

That's the problem, but the solution is a bit more involved, because you're using compiled templates. It may be as easy as renaming the file to friends/friend.hbs, or adding it into a folder called 'friends.'

Comment: That's false, that's only for routes under a resource.  His template names should be friends and friend.

Comment: You are correct, @kingpin2k -- My answer only applies if you are using a route beneath that resource, not two resources.